# How to run VS2010 Express and VS2010 Ultimate from MSDNAA on one machine?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010

Is there any possibility to run two different editions of Visual Studio 2010 on one Windows 7 installation? I have a MSDNAA version of VS2010 Ultimate, but need VS2010 Express for work. I am using two different Windows accounts, if it helps.

Comment: But isn't Ultimate a superset of Express?  What is the point of using Express when you have Ultimate installed?

Comment: I am having students licence on VS2010 Ultimate, but it's limited to non-commercial use. I'd like to use VS2010 Ultimate for my university projects, but VS2010 Express for work.